# Erro nas raízes de Bhaskara

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void func(double x1, double x2, double x3, double *delta, double *r1, double *r2);

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("log.txt","w");  
    double x1, x2, x3, delta, r1=0, r2=0;
    printf("entre com as tres raizes;\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &x1, &x2, &x3);
    func(x1, x2, x3, &delta, &r1, &r2);
    printf("delta = %.1lf \nraiz 1 = %.1lf \nraiz 2 = %.1lf\n", delta, r1, r2); 
    fprintf(file,"delta = %.2lf\nRaiz 1 = %.2lf\nRaiz 2 = %.2lf", delta, r1, r2);
    fclose(file);

}
void func(double x1, double x2, double x3, double *delta, double *r1, double *r2){
    *delta=pow(x2, 2)-4*(x1)*(x3);
    if(delta>0)
        printf("raizes distintas\n");
    else if(delta=0)
        printf("ha so uma raiz real\n");
    else
        printf("nao ha raiz real\n");
    *r1=-x2+sqrt(*delta)/2*x1;
    *r2=-x2-sqrt(*delta)/2*x1;
}
```

Os resultados de "r1" e r2" não batem se fizermos a conta na mão.
Por exemplo, para a=1, b=-13, c=22, r1=17,5 e r2=8,5. Era para estar dando 11 para r1 e 2 para r2. 
Obrigado!
Obs. Fórmula de Bhaskara.

Comment: Ola, estou lendo o codigo e vejo que a formula de bhaskara nao esta correta.
acho que deveria ser assim:


r1=(-x2+sqrt(*delta))/2*x1

Comment: Olá, era isso mesmo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na precedência, da maneira que está fazendo a raiz1 se comporta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poxa! Era isso mesmo. Obrigado!